# USMT workgroup to domain

Tags: windows, usmt

I am using USMT to migrate a large amount of computers from workgroup profiles to domain profiles.

My scanstate is:

```
scanstate.exe C:\temp\migration /ue:*\* /ui:"%computername%\@localUser@" /o /vsc /i:migdocs.xml /i:migapp.xml  /i:"C:\temp\USMT-Deploy\Config.xml"
```

My loadstate is:

```
loadstate.exe C:\temp\migration /c  /mu:"%computername%\@localUser@:@domain@\@domainUser@" /auto /i:migdocs.xml /i:migapp.xml /i:"C:\temp\USMT-Deploy\Config.xml"
```

My config.xml is located here: https://github.com/safetynet-jharrand/USMT-Config/blob/main/config.xml

I am using a custom config to bring across the user AppData and AppData local. I know its not ideal but needed for this project.

Right now I am having to log into the domain account and then run the script to use USMT. Is there a flag or option I can put in the config.xml file to create the domain user profile after it has already been domain joined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for anyone else having the problem was I needed to add the following exclusion rules for appdata local:

```
<exclude>
    <objectSet>
        <pattern type="File">%CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA%\IconCache.db [*]</pattern>
        <pattern type="File">%CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\* [*]</pattern>
        <pattern type="File">%CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA%\Microsoft\InputPersonalization\* [*]</pattern>   
    </objectSet>
</exclude>
```